# Issues calling saveChanges with Breezjs

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I'm trying to get breeze to work with my webapi/odata service against an Entity framework model with a sql backend.

I've got it to retrieve data from my database, bit am having trouble when I do a createEntity() and then call saveChanges().

I've configured my batch route like this

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(
              routeName: "WebApiBatch",
              routeTemplate: "odata/$batch",
              batchHandler: new System.Web.Http.Batch.DefaultHttpBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

When I call save changes I get an http 500 server error, with the message:

```
Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content type header with a value of 'application/http; msgtype=request'.
Parameter name: content
```

the stream sent to the server is :

```
    POST http://gx9020-01:91/odata/$batch HTTP/1.1
Accept: multipart/mixed
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_9245-db9a-4873
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
Referer: http://localhost:61678/WebForm1.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 731
DNT: 1
Host: gx9020-01:91
Pragma: no-cache


--batch_9245-db9a-4873
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_0952-3d90-c3e2

--changeset_0952-3d90-c3e2
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST odata/MAP_Counterparty HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 1
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Content-Type: application/json
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

{"MAP_CounterpartyID":-1,"SOURCE_SYSTEM":null,"TARGET_SYSTEM":null,"SOURCE_CODE":null,"TARGET_CODE":null,"TARGET_CODE2":null,"DRT_ID":null,"CREATE_DATETIME":null,"MODIFY_DATETIME":null,"Create_User":null,"Modify_User":null}
--changeset_0952-3d90-c3e2--

--batch_9245-db9a-4873--
```

How can I get the saveChanges() working?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I was using DefaultHttpBatchHandler instead of DefaultODataBatchHandler.